# dplyr filter() inside of function with optional variables (filter_if maybe?)

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filtering, tidyverse

I'm trying to write function that will perform filtering based on some optional user variables to threshold the input data before plotting either the filtered or unfiltered data.  In this example where `data` is data.frame with multiple columns including two of interest (`var1` and `var2`):

```
example_func <- function(
  data,
  low_cutoff_var1 = NULL,
  high_cutoff_var1 = NULL,
  low_cutoff_var2 = NULL,
  high_cutoff_var2 = NULL) {
...
}
```

Now as part of this function I would like to filter the input `data` using the cutoffs if the user supplies them before plotting the data (either filtered or unfiltered depending on user choices).  The filtering step would be:

```
data_filtered <- data %>% 
  filter(var1 > low_cutoff_var1 &
         var1 < high_cutoff_var1 &
         var2 > low_cutoff_var2 &
         var2 < high_cutoff_var2)
```

However, the issue is if one or more of the cutoffs is `NULL` then the filter doesn't work.

Now I know could do things step-by-step for each of the cutoffs one at a time.
i.e.:

```
if (!is.null(x = low_cutoff_var1) {
  data_filtered <- data %>% 
    filter(var1 > low_cutoff_var1)
}
if (!is.null(x = high_cutoff_var1) {
etc
```

However, that seems inelegant and there is probably better way to write this function.  I feel like maybe `filter_if` is the right choice but I'm having trouble with the syntax of that and how to use in my specific case.

Any advice on easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do would be great!

Thanks!
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using NULL as the default values use -Inf and Inf.

```
example_func <- function(data,
    low_cutoff_var1 = -Inf, high_cutoff_var1 = Inf,
    low_cutoff_var2 = -Inf, high_cutoff_var2 = Inf) {
  data %>% 
    filter(between(var1, low_cutoff_var1, high_cutoff_var1),
           between(var2, low_cutoff_var2, high_cutoff_var2))
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way:

```
example_func <- function(
    data,
    low_cutoff_var1 = NULL,
    high_cutoff_var1 = NULL,
    low_cutoff_var2 = NULL,
    high_cutoff_var2 = NULL) {
    
    arg_values <- match.call()
    filter_funs <- rlang::exprs(
        var1 > low_cutoff_var1, var1 < high_cutoff_var1,
        var2 > low_cutoff_var2, var2 < high_cutoff_var2
    )
    filter_funs <- filter_funs[!sapply(arg_values, is.null)[3:6]]
    
    data_filtered <- data %>% filter(!!!filter_funs)
    return(data_filtered)
}
```

Some tests:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(var1 = c(1, 2, 3), var2 = c(4, 5, 6))
example_func(data, 1, 3, 4, 6)
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#    var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     5
example_func(data, NULL, 4, 3, 6)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4
# 2     2     5
example_func(data, NULL, NULL, NULL, 6)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4
# 2     2     5
example_func(data, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#    var1  var2
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     4
# 2     2     5
# 3     3     6
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think the other solution posted works better in terms of simplified code but thanks very much!